# How do I list the_tags() into HTML data-attribute

Tags: php, theme-development, functions

I'm new to wordpress and trying to make a theme. I'm using a jQuery filter script on a page of posts that filters the posts nested in an unordered list using the HTML data-attribute as a hook in the list items.

I want to use each post's tags as the data attribute hook. I've looked up variations of the_tags() functions, but I can't seem to create one that will simply list the tags as separated by commas without the extra anchor tags, etc.

This is the closest I can get to what I want:

```
<li class="griditemleft" data-="<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
foreach($posttags as $tag) {
echo $sep . $tag->name; $sep = ', ';
}
}
?>">
```

It looks right in the first list item, but the subsequent list items have an extra comma at the beginning of the data attribute string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_encode()`:

```
<li class="griditemleft" data-tags="<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
$data = array();
foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $data[] = $tag->name;
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Later, in your JavaScript, iterate over the `li` items and for each item use:

```
// get an array of tag names with jQuery's parseJSON()
var itemtags = $.parseJSON( item.data('tags') );
```

See [jQuery parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) for details.

### Update

Actually, you don’t even need `parseJSON()` in your case, it is much easier with simple tag names. Let’s take a simple function to build a list of the last five posts:

```
add_action( 'wpse_69446_post_list', 'wpse_69446_post_list' );
function wpse_69446_post_list()
{
    $output = '';
    $posts  = get_posts();

    if ( ! $posts )
        return;

    foreach ( $posts as $post )
    {
        $tags      = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
        $tag_names = array ();
        $tag_data = '';

        if ( $tags )
        {
            foreach ( $tags as $tag )
            {
                $tag_names[] = $tag->name;
            }
            $tag_data = json_encode( $tag_names );
        }

        $output .= sprintf(
            '<li data-tags=\'%1$s\'><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a></li>',
            $tag_data,
            get_permalink( $post->ID ),
            get_the_title( $post->ID )
        );
    }
    print "<ul class='wpse_69446_post_list'>$output</ul>";

    // you have to enqueue jQuery first.
    // This is just as oversimplified demonstration.
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_69446_js' );
}
```

Call it in your theme files with

```
do_action( 'wpse_69446_post_list' );
```

Now we need the script for the footer:

```
function wpse_69446_js()
{
    ?>
<script>
jQuery( function($) {
    $('.wpse_69446_post_list li').each( function( i, item ) {
        var li = $(item).find( 'li' );
        console.info( 'item li:', li );
        // an array or undefined if there are no tags
        console.info( 'itemtags:', $(item).data( 'tags' ) );
    });
});
</script>
    <?php
}
```

The `itemtags` are an array now or `undefined` (empty).

[image: console output]

Now you can iterate over that array and do something awesome. :)

Comment: Thanks very much for answering this. I've been able to incorporate the json_encode on the page, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the jQuery parseJSON. This is what the "data-tag" looks like without parseJSON working: `<li class="threecol" data-="["branding","logo"]"> May you give me an example of how to iterate over the li items in JavaScript?

Comment: Oh, you should use single quotes around the JSON encoded data. I’ll fix the example.

Comment: Hey @toscho, any luck fixing the example? I haven't figured out how get it all to work yet. Thanks again for any help you can give.

Comment: @kyle See my update.

Comment: Hey @toscho Thanks for taking the time to reply. I worked with the code you gave me and the array was still outputting `["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]`. So, when calling the $tag_data inside `sprintf()` I used `str_replace()` to remove the unnecessary characters and add necessary blank spaces after the commas like so: `str_replace(',', ', ', str_replace(array('[',']','"'),'', $tag_data))` Still, I'm not sure I would have figured it out without your initial help. Thanks again! Can I buy you a beer?